# How can I make a child component div show an icon when clicked on, and not show up on other divs of the same kind?

Tags: angular, typescript

On my child component div I have it set up to show information from an object from the parent component. When I the web app starts it shows 3 divs as intended.  They have names and messages from the object I created, but when I click on one div to make the icon appear on that div, all the other icons for the other divs activate.

Parent Component  HTML

```
<div>
          <app-comment [message]="email" (messageEvent) = receiveMessage($event)> 
          </app-comment>
          </div>
```

Parent Component TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Email {
  name: string;
  date: number;
  subject: string;
  comment: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'websiteLayout';

  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  public email : Email[];
  public newEmail: Email;

  constructor() {
    this.email = [{
      name: 'Robert',
      date: 1993, 
      subject:'First Email', 
      comment: 'This is an email. This is a cool email.'
    }];

    this.newEmail = {
      name: 'Jorge', 
      date: 1991, 
      subject: 'Hello', 
      comment: "Hello how are you???"
    };

    this.email.push(this.newEmail);

    this.newEmail = {
      name: 'Chung',
      date: 2018,
      subject: 'What is Chungus?',
      comment: 'According to Urban Dictionary, one of the top definitions for Chungus is An overweight giant earth destroying, god killing rabbit. In the memes, its basically a picture of a fat Bugs Bunny. ... The word "chungus" was coined by video game journalist Jim Sterling years before the meme went viral.'
    };

    this.email.push(this.newEmail);


  }

  goo(){

  this.x = this.x + 1;
  this.y = this.x % 2;

  if (this.y === 0){
  console.log(this.x + " " + this.y);
  // document.getElementById("redd").style.border = "5px solid red";
  document.getElementById("redd").style.display = "none";
  }

  if (this.y === 1){
    console.log(this.x + " " + this.y);
    // document.getElementById("redd").style.border = "5px solid blue";
    document.getElementById("redd").style.display = "block";
  }


}

  ///This method adds poeples information to the json object
  addEmail(namee: string, datee: number, subjectt: string, commentt:string) {
    if (namee) {
      this.newEmail = { name: namee, date: datee, subject: subjectt, comment: commentt };
      this.email.push(this.newEmail);
    }

  }



  messagee:string='hi';
  //Added this for childToParent
  receiveMessage($event){
    this.messagee = $event;
  }









}
```

Child component HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let emaill of message" >

        <div (click)="onClick()" class="container">
        <div  class = "mw-100 " id="c" style="border-radius: 10px;" >

        <div style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom:0;
        ">
        <div *ngIf = "show"><i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i></div>

          <!--Name-->
          <p>{{ emaill.name }}</p>
          <!--Date-->
          <p>{{ emaill.date }}</p>
        </div>

        <div style = "padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0;">
         <!--Subject-->
         <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style= "color: blue;"></i> -->
         <p>{{ emaill.subject}}</p> 
        </div>

        <div style = "padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0;">
            <!--Comments-->
            <p>{{ emaill.comment}}</p>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Child Component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: './comment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment.component.scss']
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {

  public show:boolean=true;


  @Input() message: Object ;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(){
    this.show= !this.show
  }

  goo(){
    console.log("helllloooooooo");
  }

  //this is where I add things for ChildToParent
  messagee:string = "hola mundo";

  @Output() messageeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  sendMessage(){
        this.messageeEvent.emit(this.messagee);
    }


  myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("c").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  }




}
```

I want each div to be separate and not activate all of them at the same time

Comment: Share the component code as well. From the template, it is not evident what you are doing.

Comment: ok, I added the TS code

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-25xget)

You can change your `show` variable to be a `number` if you can only have one selected, or an array of numbers if you can have more than one at a time.
Then you can change your `ngFor` to have an index as well, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let emaill of message; let i = index">
```

Then on your `onClick` method you pass the index, and change the logic for your `ngIf`.

If you can only have one selected:

```
show: number;

onClick(index: number) {
  this.show = index;
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="show === i"><i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i></div>
```

If you can have multiple selected:

```
show: number[] = [];

onClick(index: number) {
  if (this.isSelected(index)) {
    this.show = this.show.filter(i => i !== index);
  } else {
    this.show.push(index);
  }
}

isSelected(index: number): boolean {
  return this.show.some(i => index === i);
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="isSelected(i)"><i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i></div>
```

Comment: i tried the source code for multiple selected and got an error.  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 18 in [show.some(index => index === i)] in ng:///AppModule/CommentComponent.html@11:13 ("

Comment: I tried the other source code also for if i only selected one but nothing happen when i clicked on a div and no errors were shown

Comment: Hi, my bad, updated the code and added a stackblitz for you to see it in action and apply to your needs.